# How to stop page change on Ajax Form Posting in MVC Mobile

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am creating an application on MVC Mobile and having a problem. Here i have a Partial view load on a page run-time by ajax. In which i have a simple form which will submit with ajax request like bellow:

```
@model Test.Models.TestModel
@using (this.Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Test", Model, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divResult", LoadingElementId = "loading", LoadingElementDuration = 2000, HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { id = "frmCreate" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="messageBox">@Html.Raw(TempData["Message"])</div>
    <div class="atmForm">
        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @placeholder = "Name", @class = "inputStyle" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Notes)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Notes, new { @placeholder = "Notes", @class = "inputStyle" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Notes)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions2 clearfix">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block" value="Create" data-ajax="false" id="btnFormSubmit" />
    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#frmCreate");
</script>
```

The problem is when user submit the form the controller called twice. First time it return the partial view and then again it calls and then jQuery Mobile change the page. I am Using MVC4 with jQuery Mobile 1.1.0

(please note that create.cshtml (desktop ver) works fine but create.Mobile.cshtml (mobility ver) havng this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not submit the form, use `$("#myForm").serialize()` as ajax data.